# How to extract "Month" from YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS using regexExtract?

Tags: regex

I am looking to extract only Month in the birthday contact field we have in out tool. The birthday field is in format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS via RegeX Extract. Can somebody please help.

Thanks

Comment: Why regex? Just extract characters in the 6th and 7th position. Or parse as a date-time object and ask to extract month, such as `LocalDateTime` and `Month` in Java.

Comment: We have an application where we can leverage regex extract only, hence I need  that.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can try to use the following regex `/-([0-9]+)-/` because your month is always trapped between two dashes, and the parentheses will capture only the month.

Comment: `\d+` is bit shorter ;)

Comment: Thanks Carol. I tried but it is not giving me any value on testing the above regex.